# Ethereum private testnet failing due to peers not connecting

Tags: ethereum, go-ethereum, private-network

##### The problem

I want to create a private Ethereum network, however my two peers refuse to connect. They always fail with the following error: `Snapshot extension registration failed   peer=af5dfeb7   err="peer connected on snap without compatible eth support"`.

##### My attempted fixes

- Setting `--snapshot=false` produces the same error
- Changing the `--syncmode` to full, fast or light made no difference
- Adding the peers manually with `admin.addPeer(${peer1.admin.nodeInfo.enode})` returns true, however `net.peerCount` and `admin.peers.length` return `0`
- Changing the chainId did not produce any different results
- Waiting did not help

##### My setup proccess

###### Creating the peers:

```sh
geth init --datadir "peer1" genesis.json
geth init --datadir "peer2" genesis.json
```

###### Starting the peers and opening the console:

```sh
geth --datadir "peer1" --networkid 1111 --port 30401 console 2>peer1.log
geth --datadir "peer2" --networkid 1111 --port 30402 console 2>peer2.log
```

###### The genesis file (Created by `puppeth`)

```json
{
  "config": {
    "chainId": 1111,
    "homesteadBlock": 0,
    "eip150Block": 0,
    "eip150Hash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "eip155Block": 0,
    "eip158Block": 0,
    "byzantiumBlock": 0,
    "constantinopleBlock": 0,
    "petersburgBlock": 0,
    "istanbulBlock": 0,
    "ethash": {}
  },
  "nonce": "0x0",
  "timestamp": "0x61af5dd9",
  "extraData": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "gasLimit": "0x47b760",
  "difficulty": "0x1",
  "mixHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "coinbase": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "alloc": {},
  "number": "0x0",
  "gasUsed": "0x0",
  "parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "baseFeePerGas": null
}
```

###### Geth version info

```
Geth
Version: 1.10.13-stable
Git Commit: 7a0c19f813e285516f4b525305fd73b625d2dec8
Architecture: amd64
Go Version: go1.17.2
Operating System: linux
GOPATH=
GOROOT=go
```